# JQuery auto complete with ajax response for data set is not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm facing issue with jquery autocomplete with ajax data as source. The data which is returning is proper and it is not issuing any errors. But still the results are not displaying as they should.

I have followed all the stackoverflow questions related this issue. And everything is pointing to what I have done. So it is not a duplicate of any of those questions.

If I use local variable data as data source, everything working as expected. It is not issue with UI as the same code is used for both the local variables and the ajax data.

My Code is:

```
$("#dTSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.ajax({                
            type: "POST",
              url: "{{path('dataSearch')}}",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                type: "dashboardType",
                searchTerm: $("#dTSearch").val()
              },
            success: function (data) {                  
              if(data.status == 200) {
                console.log(data.data);
                //response( data.data );
                //var dataSet = $.parseJSON(data);
                response($.map(data.data, function (item, i) {
                  //alert(item.value);
                  return {
                      id: item.id,
                      label: item.label,
                      value: item.value
                    };
                  })
                );
              }
            },
            error: function (data) {
              alert('error!');
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          alert(ui.item.value);
          return false;
        },
        open: function() {
          $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 100);
          return false;
        }
      });

      $("#dTSearch1").autocomplete({
        source: dashboardTypes,
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          $("#onlyFunctionalDiv").show();
        },
        open: function() {
          //$( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
          $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 100);
          return false;
        }
      });
```

I used the direct "response" method and "Map" in "Response" method. Nothing seems to be working.

When I consoled the results and put up alerts everything seems to be fine.

Below images shows the results and console logs I used.

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

In the first picture, the source is local variable and it is displaying the results when user start typing. Below is the console log of the same local variable.

The second picture is for the ajax response. When user types "func" it is calling the ajax and response is printing. But the results are not displaying as they should. The green color box indicates the response of a local variable and the red color box shows the ajax response data. Both seems to be same. But something is missing and it is not displaying the results when result set is available.

Can someone help me, what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. The problem is trailing semi-colon ";" at the end of return statement in the response method.

Changes in the code is:

```
response($.map(data.data, function (item, i) {
    //alert(item.value);
    return {
        id: item.id,
        label: item.label,
        value: item.value
    }
  })
);
```

I have removed the trailing semi-colon at the end of the return statement.